# ActiveSheets.Copy generates Path/File Acces Error (Error 75)

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I would like to copy the active Excel sheet (the one the  user has currently manually selected) and save it as a workbook to a specified folder.

I am using code that I know works (it is copied from another user). Whenever the code hits the `ActiveSheet.Copy` line, it stops and shows a Path/File access error (Error 75).

If I remove the `ActiveSheet.Copy` line of code, the code works fine but it  saves the entire workbook to the folder instead of the active sheet. I noticed  that if  I try to  manually copy a sheet to a new Workbook in Excel, this works fine for a **.xlsx** workbook but if the workbook is **.xlsm**, the manual process does not work.

**To be clear,** the manual process is:

- right click on a tab/worksheet
- select Move or Copy from the menu
- tick the "Create a copy" box
- select "new book" from the drop down menu

This should create a new workbook with the  sheet you had  selected.  The same person that gave me the  code that works on their machine is able to copy a worksheet manually to a new workbook even from a workbook with a .xlsm extension.

I have a brand new ThinkPad and I have not changed any default  settings. I have looked online for help with this issue but can't find any relevant answers. It does  seem to be a settings issue  of  some sort because the code and  the  manual process works on my friends computer but does not  on mine.

**May 30th Update:**
Thank you for the responses and for the  formatting help. I have tried to observe the formatting conventions in this new update.

When the code reaches  the  `ActiveSheet.Copy` line and stops, the following is the  sequence of events:

1. Path/File Access Error
2. Hit "Help" - it displays Path/File access error 75 and takes me to Microsoft's URL - I found nothing of help on the Error 75 help page
3. Run Time Error '1004' "We couldn't copy this sheet" is displayed.
4. When I hit the debug button on the  run time error, it just highlights in yellow the `ActiveSheet.Copy`line of code. No more messages are displayed.

Please note: I was running the code on One Drive in a Workbook.xlsm and trying to save to the local drive on my computer. When I removed the `ActiveSheet.Copy`line of code, I  was able to save the  entire workbook.xlsm to the appropriate folder so that makes me think it is not a path issues.

However, when I moved the workbook.xlsm with the code to the local drive, I was able to run the macro successfully with the `ActiveSheet.Copy`line of code. This happened yesterday after I posted my original question. 
I found that  when I manually  clicked  on a tab(sheet) to copy and save it to a new workbook, that also worked for the workbook.xlsm as long as it was on the local drive.

I was be able to save the entire workbook.xlsm (not a sheet) to my local C: drive from the One Drive when I removed the `ActiveSheet.Copy`line of code.  This makes me think it is not a path issue because I am able to save to the folder I specify, I just can't copy and save a  sheet.   I do not consider the case closed and am still struggling to understand 1) Why I can't run the code with the `ActiveSheet.Copy`line of code from the One Drive; 2) why the manual process of copying a sheet to a new workbook does not work on One Drive in xlsm but does on the local drive.

Here is  the code:

```
  Sub SaveMe()

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim MyTm As String          'Holds the Territory Manager "Code"
Dim MySavePath As Variant   'Holds the path to save the file
Dim MyFileName As String    'Holds the file name
Dim MyYear As Integer       'Holds the year
Dim MyMonth As Integer      'Holds the month
Dim MyDay As Integer        'Holds the day

MyYear = Year(Now)
MyMonth = Month(Now)
MyDay = Day(Now)

MyTm = Left(ActiveSheet.Name, 4)
MySavePath = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(MyTm, Range("TMSavePath"), 2, False)


    ActiveSheet.Copy

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        MySavePath & "\" & MyYear & MyMonth & MyDay & " - " & ActiveSheet.Name & ".xlsx", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close

'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Always helps to post your code.

Comment: What happens if you hit "Debug" when the error comes up?

Comment: Hi Tim. I amended my original question yesterday to provide updates including the  code. When I hit "Debug", the ActiveSheet.Copy line of code is highlighted in yellow and I can't proceed so I just have to hit "End". I explain the sequence of errors in the amended question. I mention in the amend that I was subsequently able to run the original code when I moved the workbook.xlsm from the One Drive to the local drive. Are there  bug issues running certain types of code from the One Drive?

Comment: If you open the settings in your VB editor, what is the selected error handling option?  "Break in class module" is the most useful one in my experience.  Without that you cannot debug in class code which might be the source of the error.

Comment: Hi Tim. The selected error handling option was "Break on Unhandled Errors." I  switched to  "Break in class module." When  I ran the code, it  still behaved as before with the 'ActiveSheet.Copy' line triggering an error and with the  same error messages as before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Sub moveActvieSheetToAnotherWB()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim wb As String
Dim sht As String
Dim newWb As Workbook

wb = ActiveWorkbook.Name
sht = ActiveSheet.Name
'

Set newWb = Workbooks.Add
Workbooks(wb).Sheets(sht).Copy before:=newWb.Sheets(1)

'disable popup before delete empty tab
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
newWb.Sheets(2).Delete

'full path
'newWb.SaveAs "newFilename.xlsx"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Konrad. Thank  you for your help and  the code you provided. I ran this in a new module on my workbook.xlsm. It generated the same sequence of errors once the code reached 'Workbooks(wb).Sheets(sht).Copy before:=newWb.Sheets(1)'. "Path/File Access Error"; "Run-time error '1004'  - We couldn't copy thisr sheet". This is  most peculiar. I am running the  code from One Drive. When I  tried my orignal code on the local drive yesterday, it worked. Is there an issue with running some types of macros on One Drive? I have run many so far with no problems.

Comment: I don't know what causes that error, however you can try to copy all cells from a sheet instead of whole sheet,
Sheets(1).Cells.Copy
Sheets(2).Range("A1").PasteSpecial

Comment: Hi Konrad, Thank you for your response. The code you gave works but it  copies from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 within the  same workbook. The code I am trying  to run will allow the  user to  select a sheet and then have that  sheet copied to a new workbook which consists of just that sheet. This new workbook will be saved. However, I am unable to run this on my One Drive. The code does run on my local drive. This is  very strange.